# Prevent dispose to cancel network request

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using RxJava2 and Retrofit2 for handling network requests.

I have cycle where `doOnNext` should always be ran, but my `Activity` which is the observer calls `dispose()` when it is destroyed and that causes retrofit to cancel the request.

```
java.io.IOException: Canceled
```

Is there a way to let the request complete but only dispose the UI level observer?

```
mApi.doSomethingImportant()
    .doOnNext(new Consumer<ImportantResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(ImportantResponse response) throws Exception {
            // Store data, should always get here if request is success
        }
    })
    .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            // Store error, should always get here if request fails
        }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(observer); // observer reports success/fail on UI if not disposed
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us a minimum, complete example? It makes it much easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to achieve the wanted behaviour by wrapping the observer with another, but I'm sure there is some elegant way to do this.

```
...
.subscribe(new NonDisposableObserver<>(observer)
```

Where `NonDisposableObserver` class is following:

```
public class NonDisposableObserver<T> implements Observer<T> {

    private DisposableObserver<T> observer;

    public NonDisposableObserver(DisposableObserver<T> observer) {
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T t) {
        if (!observer.isDisposed()) {
            observer.onNext(t);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        if (!observer.isDisposed()) {
            observer.onError(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        if (!observer.isDisposed()) {
            observer.onComplete();
        }
    }
}
```